# NetworkManager via D-Bus: Add a network bridge

Tags: network-manager, dbus, nmcli

I'm trying to use the [D-Bus interface](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/spec.html) of [NetworkManager](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager) to add and enable a network bridge connection. Basically I'm trying to mimic this command:

```
nmcli connection add type bridge ifname br0 stp no
```

This one-liner creates and activates a new connection, but it also creates a new virtual device `br0`.

The D-Bus API [reference](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/gdbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.html) for the `/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager` lists the following methods:

- [AddAndActivateConnection](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/gdbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.html#gdbus-method-org-freedesktop-NetworkManager.AddAndActivateConnection)
- [AddAndActivateConnection2](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/gdbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.html#gdbus-method-org-freedesktop-NetworkManager.AddAndActivateConnection2)

Both have a similar signature and require a device as input, so an existing device that can be retrieved via the D-Bus [GetDevices](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/gdbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.html#gdbus-method-org-freedesktop-NetworkManager.GetDevices) method. However, a network bridge requires a virtual device (or a virtual device is created for the network bridge?). Naturally I looked into creating a new device first and then passing it to one of the methods listed above, but the [reference](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/gdbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.html) does not offer any method for creating new devices.

I think the [nmcli implementation](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/master/clients/cli) uses the D-Bus interface under the hood, so it has to be possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nmcli con add` does not use AddAndActivate API. It also does not (itself) create the device. What happens is only that it adds a new connection profile with autoconnect enabled, which the NetworkManager will automatically activate, and thereby creating the device.

You should understand what a profile is: it's a bunch of settings for configuring a network device. And that profile may be "activated", which means to actually use the settings (and create the device). You can always manually activate a profile, or Networkmanager may do it automatically, if the conditions are right. The API to "create" a device is activating a profile. In case of a software device (eg. bridge), NetworkManager automatically creates it when you activate the profile.

AddAndActivate is called (in some cases) by `nmcli device connect` and `nmcli device wifi connect`. It's different in that it does two steps in one and it does one additional thing: the user may pass an incomplete connection profile that NetworkManager tries to fill out before adding it. As such, it's more than AddConnection + Activate connection alone. Usually, that is not what you want. Best example is to specify only the SSID in a Wi-Fi profile and AddAndActivate automatically fills in the extra settings based in the Wi-Fi scan results. With AddConnection API the profile gets fully determined by the caller and only gets completed with default settings, independent of a device (or Wi-Fi Access Point).

The device argument on D-Bus may be optional. At least for ActivateConnection API. In that case, NetworkManager will automatically find or create a suitable device. Also, the connection profile argument may be optional (if you instead provide only the device).

Yes, most Networkmanager client tools will use the same underlying D-Bus API, including nmcli. That allows you to write your own application that does what other applications do and thereby integrate with those tools. There is also libnm, a glib based library that wraps D-Bus and several client applications use that instead of talking D-Bus directly.

See also the examples at https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/ce59e749fbc99152d379b22563d6fd3295c7085a/examples

Networkmanager API is all about creating profiles (connections) and activating them.